# Proxy issue running GoogleAppEngine on local

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, google-app-engine, proxy

How can I configure my proxy settings to run my application without deploy on google servers?

I'm asking because I'm developing a feature that use another service on the Web, but I can't access this service due proxy settings. The Java SDK on GoogleAppEngine doesn't allow proxy.

In running GoogleAppEngine on my machine. And my machine is under a proxy.

I'm using Eclipse as IDE

Comment: Are you asking how to view your local? It should http://localhost:8080 as per the default App Engine SDK settings. Or are you asking how others can see your local over the internet?

Comment: No, I'm asking how my local running app can read other web services throught my proxy

Comment: So, this has nothing to with app engine, you are just trying to connect to an external web service that is blocked by a proxy. There is no programming solution to that, you need to get an exception added to your proxy, presumably by calling your network support guys.

Comment: No, this is a GoogleAppEngine configuration issue. It must have a solution. I saw in there is a way to configure, but not for java.

Comment: You're not giving enough info. Please edit your post to include code and the error you are getting.

Comment: Not enough information? I'm getting a proxy error, this is enough information! Sorry, but there is no way for adding more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java the proxy settings are usually applied at the JVM level, through the http.proxy* settings.  See here: http://info4tech.wordpress.com/2007/05/04/java-http-proxy-settings/

Simplest thing to test would be to set your JAVA_OPTS="-Dhttp.proxyHost=yourProxyURL ..." and go from there...